# SQL: How to avoid duplicate values

Tags: sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ca.id_number,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),MAX(ca.creation_time),120) as creation_time,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),MAX(cc.close_date),120) as close_date,
    cc.summary
FROM dbo.table_case ca
    INNER JOIN table_case_display cd on cd.id_number = ca.id_number
    INNER JOIN table_act_entry acte on ca.objid = acte.act_entry2case
    INNER JOIN table_gbst_elm elm on elm.objid = acte.entry_name2gbst_elm
    LEFT JOIN table_close_case cc on acte.objid = cc.close_case2act_entry 
WHERE 
    "cd"."creation_time">={ts '2004-09-30 19:58:21'} 
    AND  "ca"."id_number"<>'001' 
    AND ( "cd"."severity"='A' 
    OR "cd"."severity"='B' 
    OR "cd"."severity"='C' 
    OR "cd"."severity"='E' 
    OR "cd"."severity"='TBD') 
    AND "cd"."site_name"='Nextel International (Hosting)'
    AND (ca.creation_time>={ts '2014-03-01 00:00:00'} AND ca.creation_time<{ts '2014-04-10 00:00:01'})
GROUP BY ca.creation_time, cc.close_date, ca.id_number, cc.summary
ORDER BY ca.id_number asc
```

This is the output:

```
C00001  2014-03-10 20:35:17 NULL                    NULL
C00002  2014-03-11 03:16:01 NULL                    NULL
C00002  2014-03-11 03:16:01 2014-03-11 18:10:41     test
C00003  2014-03-07 02:53:22 NULL                    NULL
C00003  2014-03-07 02:53:22 2014-03-12 18:41:59     test
```

From the above output, it's showing duplicate IDs.
How to write a query in order to avoid this issue?

Comment: "distinct" applies to the entire line.  Your close_date data is different.  So, what is the requirement, to get the rows where its closed (column is not null), or open (where close_date is null)?

Comment: Agree @Gary_W.  You can choose to show the first value, or max value or similar, for `close_date`.  But basically you do have to make a choice.

Comment: part of the problem it's about the open "IDs". You can see, the first ID C00001 is not closed yet. C00002 is closed. The table table_close_case with LEFT JOIN is bringing "null" cases. Is there any way to avoid to bring the "null" cases if they are already closed?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
GROUP BY ca.creation_time, cc.close_date, ca.id_number, cc.summary
```

on

```
GROUP BY  ca.id_number, cc.summary
```

Comment: it's not a group by issue. Even though the syntax was wrong anyways... Thanks! It's something related with the LEFT JOIN, and I want to find way that will not consider replication cases. "IF case_is_closed THEN" Does that make sense?